# Is it possible to set an existing working copy as a remote repository?

Tags: windows, git

Currently, I have my working copy on a network drive (let's call it **X:**) and I am modifying files in the repository by an IDE running on my machine. On the same server, a web server is running and I can preview my changes instantly.

I would like to create a local git repository on my machine so that I can get rid of the network mount slow speed issues. In this case, I will have to push my changes to the current existing repository in order to preview my changes through the browser.

I wonder if it is possible to have my current working copy (which is on the same server which **X:** is pointing to) set as 'remote' repository so that changes I make in my local repository can be pushed to that?

Answer (score 0):

you can certainly do that. but it will create each push to the server as separate commits. if so use the following command on the remote server in the repo directory

```
git daemon --verbose --export-all --base-path=.git --reuseaddr --strict-paths .git/
```